# Make sure socket connection is finished and then dispose it

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a server which takes a string via a socket and manipulates it. I want to send a string to the server, read the answer, send another string and then wait for the answer on the 2nd string to finally close the transaction. The code below is my progress to achieve that. When I send the first string, I get a reply but as soon as I send the 2nd string the program "freezes" in a way of endless thinking (not an actual freeze).

The server I'm sending to, isn't mine, so I cant publish any code from it. I have it running locally though. The reply I'm expecting is around 50-60 characters. Im suspicious on the fact that the application never finishes, and what I want to do is check if the transaction is done and then close it. Since the first string is working, its the 2nd string I want to check if its done with.

```
class test {

private Socket m_Socket;
private TcpClient m_Client = new TcpClient();

public Test()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    m_Socket = m_Client.Client;
}

private void DoIt()
{
    // Connect
    if (!m_Socket.IsBound)
        m_Socket.Connect(txtHost.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));

    // Send first string
    try
    {
        string str = "asdfpojfdiogj589068d9fyugui";
        Send(m_Socket, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str), 0, str.length, 10000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

    //// Receive answer
    byte[] buffer = new byte[48];
    Receive(m_Socket, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Answer 1: "+Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    buffer = new byte[64];

    // Send string 2
    string str2 = "jasuidhj8348957y3478538hdjuhduihdfugv09im2390i490gfifjgiojdfiogj4893574y890dgydufighduifh";
    Send(m_Socket, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str2), 0, str2.Length, 10000);

    // Receive answer2
    buffer = new byte[str2.Length];
    Receive(m_Socket, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 10000);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
}

public void Send(Socket p_Socket, byte[] p_Buffer, int p_Offset, int p_Size, int p_Timeout)
{
        int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int sent = 0;
        do
        {
            if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + p_Timeout)
                throw new Exception("Timeout..");
            try
            {
                sent += p_Socket.Send(p_Buffer, p_Offset + sent, p_Size - sent, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                    ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                    ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                {
                    // socket buffer is probably full, wait and try again
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
                }
                else
                    throw ex;
            }
        } while (sent < p_Size);
}

public string Receive(Socket p_Socket, byte[] p_Buffer, int p_Offset, int p_Size, int p_Timeout)
{
    int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
    int received = 0;
    do
    {
        if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + p_Timeout)
            //throw new Exception("Timeout.");
            return p_Buffer.ToString();
        try
        {
            received += p_Socket.Receive(p_Buffer, p_Offset + received, p_Size - received, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
            {
                // socket buffer is probably empty, wait and try again
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
            else
                throw ex;
        }
    } while (received < p_Size);
    return p_Buffer.ToString();
}
}
```

The flow is started from the method DoIt() which are called from a button in the UI.

Comment: Are you sure the server only accepts two strings and no more or no less? If it only accepts one, you'll have to reconnect and send another

Comment: Since seems to be just text, if you `telnet` to the server's port and follow your process manually, does it work correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the server's second response is going to be exactly the same as the length of your second request? Because it'll get stuck in `Receive` waiting for (at least) one more byte to arrive.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I haven't tried that. I'll try that!

Comment: @JohnC Unfortunely I dont get how telnet works nowadays on Win8 :P However, I've spoken to the owner of the server that have checked the server status which and its working. Also, I'm sending one string which works good and the 2nd is the problem :(

Comment: It looks like you do [have a telnet](http://www.techulator.com/resources/5242-How-enable-Telnet-Client-Windows.aspx), which is comforting. Wait, is the server _receiving_ the second string, then? Can that string be malformed?

Comment: @user3427831 Download and use an application called 'PUTTY'

Comment: Neat! Actually, yeah, the server recieves my 2nd string and send a reply but my code doesnt seem to handle it for some reason.

Comment: I've tried to connect to the server with PuTTY but it doesn't work. I think its more cause of me using it wrong though. I didnt change any settings other than host/port.

Comment: Your `Receive` method will carry on calling the socket's `Receive` method until it has received *exactly* the number of bytes that you're requesting. Nothing in the code you've shown will cause it to return earlier if fewer bytes are actually sent by the server.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement a solution like that?